# Angular with keycloak in docker-compose cors issue

Tags: angular, docker, docker-compose

I'm having anuglar app with ngnix and keycloak. I'm getting error, which looks like CORS issue. I wasnt developing the angular app, as I was supposed to deal with backend, but now I'm stuck
Docker compose:

```
keycloak:
    depends_on:
      - keycloackDB
    container_name: local_keycloak
    environment:
      DB_VENDOR: postgres
      DB_ADDR: keycloackDB
      DB_DATABASE: keycloack
      DB_USER: keycloack
      DB_PASSWORD: keycloack
      KEYCLOAK_USER: admin
      KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD: admin
    image: jboss/keycloak
    ports:
      - "28080:8080"
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
        - keycloak_data:/data
        - ./keycloak/providers:/opt/jboss/keycloak/providers


  front:
    image: repository/front:1.8
    ports:
      - 4200:80
```

Client settings in which I've set web origins:
[keycloak clinet config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6IWah.png)

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Se: {"headers":{"normalizedNames":{},"lazyUpdate":null,"headers":{}},"status":0,"statusText":"Unknown Error","url":"http://keycloak:8080/auth/realms/management/.well-known/openid-configuration","ok":false,"name":"HttpErrorResponse","message":"Http failure response for http://keycloak:8080/auth/realms/management/.well-known/openid-configuration: 0 Unknown Error","error":{"isTrusted":true}}
    at z (polyfills.974e56a2f7b98a12.js:1:16026)
    at z (polyfills.974e56a2f7b98a12.js:1:15561)
    at polyfills.974e56a2f7b98a12.js:1:16874
    at v.invokeTask (polyfills.974e56a2f7b98a12.js:1:7223)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (main.9f1d51fe6882ab72.js:1:640761)
    at v.invokeTask (polyfills.974e56a2f7b98a12.js:1:7144)
    at M.runTask (polyfills.974e56a2f7b98a12.js:1:2618)
    at _ (polyfills.974e56a2f7b98a12.js:1:9238)
    at p.invokeTask [as invoke] (polyfills.974e56a2f7b98a12.js:1:8304)
    at Z (polyfills.974e56a2f7b98a12.js:1:20793)
```

Comment: You missed `keycloackDB` part in docker-compose.yml , How to reproduce it for your Error?

Comment: You find something, I'm facing the same problem